In Cryptography KAT tests how to use SHA256 correctly?
I got a project on github which I want to use for a school project and all relevant data for the question is in the "KAT" folder. However, I got 1 problem. It contains .rsp1 files with the parameters count, seed, mlen, msg, pk, sk, smlen, sm. I know what these mean and in this project the author says that these files are SHA256 hashed into the .txt files because the keys are extremely long which I of course can see.
project on github: https://github.com/mjosaarinen/uov-py/tree/main
However, if I add all the parameters of the .rsp1 files into one block and apply SHA256 I don't get the output of the .txt files. I get the correct output from the code which is also in the .txt files. I just want to know how to hash the data in the .rsp1 files so it becomes the same as the outputs in the .txt files. It would be amazing if anybody could try and tell me if they used all parameters or not to get the .txt outputs.
Thank you for any help.
